# Three captions of same size inside of a div element

Tags: html, css, angular, material-design

I want to make layout of div inside which there are 3 captions fitting into same size!

I am using angular materialise - Normal html / css also works for me.

I have tried

```
<div>
 <label> Label 1 </label>
 <label> Label 2 </label>
 <label> Label 3 </label>
</div>
```

I have attached an image of what I need.

[image]

Should I use same 3 divs inside? or span / labels?

Comment: div, label, span, p and many other tags will work fine for the layout. Only thing is you should style it properly. and usage of meaningful elements will improve your code quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what u needed.

```css
.tabs label {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 0;
    float: left;
}
label.selected {
    background: #ccc;
}
.tabs label:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

.tabs {
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
 <label class="selected"> Label 1 </label>
 <label> Label 2 </label>
 <label> Label 3 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much Awsme Sandy !! Its working perfectly fine for me :)

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee thanks, please dont forget to mark it helpful :)